# Using arrays in C++ CT reconstruction algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm developing a CT reconstruction algorithm using C++. I'm using C++ because I need to use a library written in C++ that will let me read/write a specific file format.

This reconstruction algorithm involves working with 3D and 2D images. I've written similar algorithms in C and MATLAB using arrays. However, I've read that, in C++, arrays are "evil" (see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html). The way I use arrays to manipulate images (in C) is the following (this creates a 3D array that will be used as a 3D image):

```
int i,j;
int *** image;  /* another way to make a 5x12x27 array */

image = (int ***) malloc(depth * sizeof(int **));
for (i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
    image[i] = (int **) malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
    for (j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
        image[i][j] = (int *) malloc(width * sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

or I use 1-dimensional arrays and do index arithmetic to simulate 3D data. At the end, I free the necessary memory.
I have read that there are equivalent ways of doing this in C++. I've seen that I could create my own matrix class that uses vectors of vectors (from STL) or that I could use the boost-matrix library. The problem is that this makes my code look bloated.

My questions are:

1) Is there a reason to not use arrays for this purpose? Why should I use the more complicated data structures?

2) I don't think I'll use the advantages of containers (as seen in the C++ FAQ lite link I posted). Is there something I'm not seeing?

3) The C++ FAQ lite mentions that arrays will make me less productive. I don't really see how that applies to my case. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1):

I know it looks difficult at first, and your code seems simple - but eventually yours is going to hurt.

Use a library like [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html), or consider a custom 3D image toolkit like [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/)

Comment: Because everytime somebody looks at a lib written by the best experts and thinks- that's too complex I can do it better they later discover some reason for the complexity which bites them in the ass. Does your solution scale when it needs more than 4Gb of Ram, doesit leak memory, does it handle multiple threads, is it cache efficent, does it scale to 64bit machines, have you written the most efficent matrix inversion routine  .... etc....

Comment: Oh ok. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Damian - although there is nothing specifically wrong with your code!

Answer (score 1):

Working at a higher level always saves you time given equal familiarity with both types of code.  It's usually simpler and you might not need to bother with some tasks like deleting.

That said, if you already have the C code and are basically converting `malloc` to `new` (or leaving it as-is) then it makes perfect sense to leave it.  No reason to duplicate work for no advantage.  If you're going to be extending it and adding more features you might want to think about a rewrite.  Image manipulation is often an intensive process and I see straight code like yours all the time for performance reasons.

Arrays have a purpose, vectors have a purpose, and so on.  You seem to understand the tradeoffs so I won't go into that.  Understanding the context of what you're doing is necessary; anyone who says that arrays are always bad or vectors are always too much overhead (etc.) probably doesn't know what they're talking about.

Comment: No, I don't have the C code. I will write something new. My other problem is that I want to use the FFTW library, and I don't know how simple (or hard) is to take one format (STL container or Boost-Array) and put it in the FFTW format. That might make the code less readable

Comment: @Damian Right. Well I suppose I'd just tell you to use your judgment. It's not too hard to create and array and fill it with the contents of an STL container, and the reverse is usually even easier. If you're confident in your ability to write it straight and think it would just slow you to use the STL then I'd say go for it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot. I'll go ahead and use my judgement. I hope I don't over complicate things :)

Answer (score 1):

if the 3D canvas has a fixed size you won't win much by using containers. I would avoid allocating the matrix in small chunks as you do, though, and just instead do

```
#define DIM_X 5
#define DIM_Y 12
#define DIM_Z 27
#define SIZE (DIM_X * DIM_Y * DIM_Z)
#define OFFS(x, y, z) (x + y * DIM_X + z * (DIM_Y * DIM_X))
```

and then

```
class 3DImage {
  private unsigned int pixel_data[SIZE];
  int & operator()(int x, int y, int z) { return pixel_data[OFFS(x,y,z)]; } 
}
```

after which you can do e.g.

```
3DImage img;
img(1,1,1) = 10;
img(2,2,2) = img(1,1,1) + 2;
```

without having any memory allocation or algorithm overhead. But as some others have noted, the choice of the data structure also depends on what kind of algorithms you are planning to run on the images. You can always however adapt a third-party algorithm e.g. for matrix inversion with a proper facade class if needed; and this flat representation is much faster than the nested arrays of pointers you wrote.

If the dimensions are not fixed compile time, you can obviously still use exactly the same approach, it's just that you need to allocate pixel_data dynamically and store the dimensions in the 3DImage object itself. Here's that version:

```
class 3DImage {
  private unsigned int *pixel_data;
  unsigned int dim_x, dim_y, dim_z;
  3DImage(int xd, int yd, int zd) { dim_x = xd; dim_y = yd; dim_z = zd;
    pixel_data = new int[dim_x * dim_y * dim_z];
  }
  virtual ~3DImage() { delete pixel_data; }
  int & operator(int x, int y, int z) {
    return pixel_data[x + y * dim_x + z * dim_y * dim_x];
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the dimension of the image is not fixed? I would need to use dynamic memory allocation, right? So, you are saying that it is easy to move from data structure to data structure if I want to use different 3rd party algorithms?

Comment: I added code for the case of not fixed dimension. It uses one call to new[] to allocate a flat array of integers. The code could be optimized by precalculating dim_y * dim_x and storing it in a class member variable because the dimensions do not change later. If you want to use 3rd party algorithms, you don't need to change the underlying datastructure but you may need to write an adapter class that mediates between the algorithm's data structure backend interface and your 3DImage class.

Answer (score 1):

**My questions are:
1) Is there a reason to not use arrays for this purpose? Why should I use the more complicated data structures?**

I personally prefer to use basic arrays. By basic I mean a 1D linear array. Say you have a 512 X 512 image, and you have 5 slices, then the image array looks like following:

```
int sizeX = 512;
int sizeY = 512;
int sizeZ = 5;
float* img = new float[sizeX * sizeY * sizeZ]
```

To access of a pixel/voxel at location `(x,y,z)`, you would need to do:

```
float val = img[z*sizeX*sizeY + y*sizeX + sizeX];
```

**2) I don't think I'll use the advantages of containers (as seen in the C++ FAQ lite link I posted). Is there something I'm not seeing?**

To use containers is more like a programming thing (easier, safer, exception catching....). If you are an algorithm guy, then it might not be your concern at all. However, one example to use `<vector>` in C++, you can always do this:

```
int sizeX = 512;
int sizeY = 512;
int sizeZ = 5;
std::vector<float> img(sizeX * sizeY * sizeZ);
float* p = &img[0];
```

**3) The C++ FAQ lite mentions that arrays will make me less productive. I don't really see how that applies to my case. What do you guys think?**

I don't see why array makes you less productive. Of course, c++ guys would prefer to use vectors to raw arrays. But again, it is just a programming thing.

Hope this helps.

**Supplement:**

The easiest way to do a 2D/3D CT recon would be to use MATLAB/python + C/C++; But again, this would require you sufficient experience when to use which. MATLAB has built in FFT/IFFT, so you don't have to write a C/C++ code for that. I remember I used KissFFT before, and it was no problem.